# Unable to define an extension method that recurses

Tags: c#

I would like to define an extension method that recurses into a nested structure of, you guessed it, exceptions. This is what I would like to do...

```
class Utils
{
    public static string TellMeEverything(this Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.InnerException?.TellMeEverything() + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}
```

But this generates a compiler error `'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'TellMeEverything' and no extension method 'TellMeEverything' accepting a first argument of type 'Exception' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Could this be considered a compiler bug?

Comment: Shouldn't the `?.` access be on the `InnerException` rather than on `ex`? If `ex` is null, you've protected the inner `TellMeEverything` call but you're still going to blow up with a null reference on `ex.Message`.

Comment: oh my goodness i must wake up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `class utils` should also be `public static` in order for it to be discoverable as an extension to `System.Exception`